# Get requested page <url> inside ajax call on some web page

Tags: ruby, ajax, parsing, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri, at this moment, I have variable which contains code of some page: `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))`. There is script in code, ajax calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">         
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#menu").kendoMenu();    
        $('.menu_item').on('click', function (e){
          $.ajax({
            url: '/movie/101299-the-hunger-games-catching-fire/images?kind=backdrop&language=' + $(this).attr('alt') + '&translate=false',
            cache: false
          }).done(function(response) {
            $('#image_panel').html(response);
          });
        });

        $.ajax({
          url: '/movie/101299-the-hunger-games-catching-fire/images?kind=backdrop&language=&translate=false', //goal
          cache: false
        }).done(function(response) {
          $('#image_panel').html(response);
        });   
      });        
</script>
```

There is some way to get second request url, and place it to the variable, I need to go to this url. Unfortunately I didn't find something about it, maybe phantomjs can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will to manually parse the script element. You can do this by using Nokogiri to get the text of the script element. Then use a regexp to find the last url:

Assuming the script is the first on the page, you can do:

```
url = doc.at_css('script').text.scan(/url: '(.*)'/).last.first
```

The following breaks the script down to provide explanation of each step:

```
# Get the text of the script element
# Note that this assumes it is the first script element (you may need to be more specific)
script = doc.at_css('script').text

# Find all urls in the script
urls = script.scan(/url: '(.*)'/)

# Of the urls found, take the last one
url = urls.last

# url is actually an array of length 1, since we used a matching group in the regex
# Take the first element of the array to get the url as a string
url = url.first
#=> "/movie/101299-the-hunger-games-catching-fire/images?kind=backdrop&language=&translate=false"
```

Comment: I notice that nokogiri doesn't return to me actual url, it returns /movie/603-the-matrix/images?kind=backdrop==false, instead of /movie/101299-the-hunger-games-catching-fire/images?kind=backdrop&language=&translate=false, maybe you know why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the right script element? The code in this answer assumed the script was the first on the page since that was the only part of the html given. If you do `puts doc.css('script').length`, what do you get?

Comment: I get this script by at_css(script:nth-child(5)). There are 17 scripts on the page. In first url doesn't present &language...&translate, and the same in second &language...&translate

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what is wrong. Based on your first comment, the wrong movie is returned? Based on your last comment... I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Nokokgiri doesn't return text that goes after ampersand in url. It's cutting &language and &tran‌​slate, so in the end of url I'm getting kind=backdrop==false instead of kind=backdrop&language=&tran‌​slate=false. Don't worry, thank you for your time and help.

Comment: It's was my mistake, I received page with xml, doc = Nokogiri::XML